# Nested Header List

Tags: code-golf

The goal of this challenge is to complete a list of consecutive nested header numbers when given a start and an end.  When given `1.1.1` and `1.1.5` you should generate `1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5`

**Specific Rules**

1. Your entry must take in a `start`, `end`, and multiple optional `range` parameters.  Parameters can be taken form STDIN (or nearest equivalent) or a file.
2. Your entry may assume valid input
3. Input will be of the following format:

   1. `start` and `end` will be strings of `.` delimited integers of the same length
   2. `start` and `end` will have three segments; (1) set values, (2) iterator, (3) trailing values.

      - The iterator is the first value which differs between `start` and `end`.
      - The set values are the values before the iterator.  These values never change
      - The trailing values are the values after the iterator.  These values iterate up as determined by the `range` parameter(s). **All trailing values in `start` and `end` will be `1`**.
   3. `range` will be a list of integers or strings (depending on which you prefer) with a length corresponding to the number of trailing values.  When there are no trailing values, `range` is not specified. The value of `range` corresponding to each trailing value determines the *inclusive upper bound* which that entry iterates to.
4. Output will be to STDOUT (or closest alternative) and will show each value separated by at least one delimiter.  Delimiter can by any character or string of characters, but it must be consistent. Output must be sorted correctly

**Examples**

```
start = '1.1.5.1', end = '1.1.6.1', range = [5]
Output: 1.1.5.1, 1.1.5.2, 1.1.5.3, 1.1.5.4, 1.1.5.5, 1.1.6.1
                                                  ^
                                                  previous value is iterated
                                                  only when iterating value
                                                  limit set by range


start = '1.1.5.1', end = '1.1.7.1', range = [5]
Output: 1.1.5.1, 1.1.5.2, 1.1.5.3, 1.1.5.4, 1.1.5.5, 1.1.6.1,
        1.1.6.2, 1.1.6.3, 1.1.6.4, 1.1.6.5, 1.1.7.1

start = '1.5.1.1', end = '1.6.1.1', range = [5,2]
Output: 1.5.1.1, 1.5.1.2, 1.5.2.1, 1.5.2.2, 1.5.3.1, 1.5.3.2, 
        1.5.4.1, 1.5.4.2, 1.5.5.1, 1.5.5.2, 1.6.1.1
```

This is code golf so shortest code by bytes wins. Standard loopholes apply.

**Bonuses**

1. Allow trailing values to be values other than `1` in `end` parameter - **12.5% off**
2. Handle incorrect number of values in `range` parameter - **12.5% off**
3. Handle `end` less than `start` by producing list in reverse - **50% off**

Bonuses are calculated off of the original byte count; a 100 byte answer which receives all bonuses will have a final score of `100 bytes - 100*(0.125+0.125+0.5) = 25 bytes`

Comment: @nimi, edited to answer both questions in your second comment.

Comment: @nimi, For bonus 3, yes that is the correct understanding

Comment: why does the second test case repeat `1.1.6.1`?

Comment: You say the set values never change - are they always `1`'s? Are all the numbers in `start` and `end` single digits, or could `1.1.22.1 to 1.1.24.1` happen?

Comment: @Maltysen, because I missed that, its just a typo, disregard

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, Set values never change, but there's no reason why they couldn't be values other than `1`.  Yes, double digit values can be present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Haskell, <s>201</s> <s>194</s> 188*0.25 = 47 bytes

```
import Data.Lists
l=length
p x=read<$>splitOn"."x
(s#e)r=intercalate".".map show<$>(fst$span(<=e)$sequence$zipWith enumFromTo s$take(l e-l r)e++r)
s!e|s<e=s#e|1<2=reverse.(e#s)
(.p).(!).p
```

I'm going for all bonuses.

"Normal" use:

```
*Main> ((.p).(!).p) "1.5.1.1" "1.6.1.1" [5,2]
["1.5.1.1","1.5.1.2","1.5.2.1","1.5.2.2","1.5.3.1","1.5.3.2","1.5.4.1",
"1.5.4.2","1.5.5.1","1.5.5.2","1.6.1.1"]
```

Bonus 1:

```
*Main> ((.p).(!).p) "1.5.1.1" "1.6.4.1" [5,2]
["1.5.1.1","1.5.1.2","1.5.2.1","1.5.2.2","1.5.3.1","1.5.3.2","1.5.4.1",
 "1.5.4.2","1.5.5.1","1.5.5.2","1.6.1.1","1.6.1.2","1.6.2.1","1.6.2.2",
 "1.6.3.1","1.6.3.2","1.6.4.1"]
```

Bonus 2:

```
*Main> ((.p).(!).p) "1.5.1.1" "1.6.1.1" [3]
["1.5.1.1","1.5.1.2","1.5.1.3","1.6.1.1"]
```

Bonus 3:

```
*Main> ((.p).(!).p) "1.6.1.1" "1.5.1.1" [5,2] 
["1.6.1.1","1.5.5.2","1.5.5.1","1.5.4.2","1.5.4.1","1.5.3.2","1.5.3.1",
 "1.5.2.2","1.5.2.1","1.5.1.2","1.5.1.1"]
```

How it works:

Split `start` and `end` into lists of numbers, e.g. `"1.5.1.1"` -> `[1,5,1,1]`. Prepend elements from `end` to `range` so that the resulting list has the same length as `end`, e.g. `[5,2]` and `"1.6.1.1"` -> `[1,6,5,2]`. Zip this list and `start` with the list building function `enumFromTo`, e.g. `[1,5,1,1]` and `[1,6,5,2]`-> `[[1],[5,6],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2]]`. `sequence` builds all combinations thereof, where numbers at position i are drawn from sublist i, -> `[[1,5,1,1],[1,5,1,2],[1,5,2,1],[1,5,2,2],...]`. Re-insert the dots and take elements as long as the they are less or equal than `end`.

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 214 bytes, no bonuses :(

```powershell
param($s,$e,$r)
$f={param($v,$w)if($w){$w[0]|%{&$f "$v.$_" $w[1..$w.Count]}}else{$v;if($v-eq$e){break}}}
$x,$y=($s-split'\.'|diff $e.split('.')).inputobject
$q=,($x..$y)
$r|%{$q+=,(1..$_)}
&$f ($s-split".$x")[0] $q
```

e.g.

```powershell
PS C:\Scripts> .\nestedh.ps1 '1.5.1.1' '1.6.1.1' @(5,2)
1.5.1.1
1.5.1.2
1.5.2.1
1.5.2.2
1.5.3.1
1.5.3.2
1.5.4.1
1.5.4.2
1.5.5.1
1.5.5.2
1.6.1.1
```

It:

- Uses `-split '\.'` feeding to `diff/Compare-Object` to find the two differing numbers, (this approach blocks the bonus where the tail values can change, because it changes the diff output).
- Builds an array of the ranges it will need for each header position, taking from the range parameters.This leaves something like `"$q=[[5,6], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2]]"`
- Those get fed into the recursive function `$f` which takes the set values prefix and a list of sublists, adds the prefix to each number, and calls itself with that as the new prefix, and the remaining sublists
- quits when it hits the `$end` string